# AnyLogic проблема совместимости

Tags: совместимость

Сделал проект в анилогик, модель счетчика. Но на другом пк оно не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает статическую картинку. Напротив времени восклицательный знак внизу. Также пропали блоки с текстом и ползунок

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решилась. уже не актуально

Comment: В таком случае в ответе стоило написать, как именно.